# Grep inside function body by function name

Tags: linux, grep

Is there any trick to grep in a **function body** by using **function name**? Furthermore I'd like to use regex instead of full function name.

***For instance***: There are many functions in linux kernel drivers with name "xxx_probe". So, I'd like to search some string inside all these functions.

Comment: I don't know of any tools that will allow you to search inside of a function.

Comment: Me either;) But I hope some command line magic trick exist)

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything greplike, but take a look at http://beyondgrep.com/more-tools/ for some tools that might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can grep the function you're looking for using `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M "(?s)int foo_probe.*?(?=^\}$)" somefile.c
```

This will start the search with "int foo_probe" and then end it at the next line that contains only a "}". The `(?s)` treats the file as a single line so that `.` matches newlines.

From there, it's easy enough to pipe it to a second grep:

```
pcregrep -M "(?s)int foo_probe.*?(?=^\}$)" somefile.c | grep something
```

I don't know what kernel source files look like, so may need some tweaking...

Answer (score 0):

`-A num` option for grep may be help. It will print `num` lines of trailing context after matching lines.

```
grep "xxx_probe(" -A after-context-num | grep "search-str"
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not only use grep but I think it is still useful.

Given this text file of functions:

```
$ cat functions.txt
function bashfunction {
    echo "bash function"
}

def python_function():
    print('python function')


sub perl_fuction {
    print "perl function\n";
}
```

If you grep for print you will get both perl and python prints:

```
$ grep print functions.txt
    print('python function')
    print "perl function\n";
```

If you want just perl function prints:

```
$ awk '/sub/,/^}$/' functions.txt | grep print
    print "perl function\n";
```

If you want just python function prints:

```
$ awk '/def/,/^$/' functions.txt | grep print
    print('python function')
```

Or for the echos in a specific bash function:

```
$ awk '/bashfunction/,/^}$/' functions.txt | grep echo
    echo "bash function"
```

Using regexes:

```
$ awk '/bash[[:alpha:]]{8}/,/^}$/' functions.txt | grep echo
    echo "bash function"
```

If your awk is `gawk` you can use shorthand operators for nicer regexes:

```
$ gawk '/bash\S+\s{$/,/^}$/' functions.txt | grep echo
    echo "bash function"
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/def/,/^$/p' functions.txt | grep print
    print('python function')
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Just give function_name a string value equal to the function name you are searching for and replace 5 with the estimated number of lines within that function block.

```
function_name="foo"
grep -A 5 -m 1 -h "ERROR\]: $function_name" $papiFileName |
              grep -B 5 "}
```